# Need an efficient mysql database schema to store points/ratings

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have four main tables-

```
1.user(user_id, name,...) 
2. post(post_id, description, ...) 
3.comment(comment_id,user_id,comment,...)
4.reply(reply_id,user_id, reply,...)
```

and

```
5.user_post(user_id,post_id)
6.post_comment(post_id,comment_id)
```

Now user can give points 1 to 10 (similar to rating) to each comment,reply and post and I also need to count the total points earned by a user with their contents(post,comment,reply). Currently I have two options.

**option 1:**
I can have a big table named `points` and store the number of points for each content with a `type` column which sacrifices `referential integrity` E.g.-

```
points(content_id, type, point, given_by)
```

OR,

**option 2:**
Having three separate tables which doesn't sacrifice `referential integrity`. E.g.-

```
post_point(post_id, point, given_by)
comment_point(comment_id, point, given_by)
reply_point(reply_id, point, given_by)
```

So, what would be the best and future proof option here or Is there any better solution ?? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to ask this in [dba.SE]

Answer (score 1):

Whether the options 1 or 2, when user visit the post, you need to sum up all the sub points, it costs much.

Suppose the option 2, you may do:

```
SELECT SUM(point) FROM post_point where post_id=100
```

If there are thousand of users give points to this post, the statement may take seconds to response.

I suggest add 1 more point column into user/post/comment/reply table,

> user(user_id, name,...) → user(user_id, name, **point**,...)
>
> post(post_id, description, ...)  → post(post_id, description, **point**, ...)
>
> ...

each time the user/post/comment/reply got any points add into the relevant one.

For example post 100 got a 1 point, you can add 1 point to the post table:

```
UPDATE post SET point=point+1 WHERE post_id=100;
```

You can also add 1 point to the post_point table if you want to track or show the given users.

```
INSERT INTO post_point VALUES('100','1','...');
```

The efficient place is when someone view this post, you can show the points by only 1 SELECT statement.

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you give an example along with the answer of one of my question - `Should i break the referential integrity or not` ?? BTW thanks for the answer @shingo .

Comment: `Should i break the referential integrity or not?` IMO it's no difference, but I prefer the 2nd, because it's more clear to understand.